# redirect a data stream from adb to a local utility - Android

Tags: android, stream, pipe, adb

I need to use the stream of data provided by a device under android in my utilities.

Under a standard Linux distribution I would do the following:

```
util -input /dev/random
```

with `adb` and Android i would like to use a `/dev/random` from the Android device as input for my local `util`. How i'm supposed to create this pipe ?

if i do

```
adb pull /dev/random random
```

adb just exits after dumping 1 complete copy but i need a constant pipe/stream.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use something like this

```
$ adb shell dd if=/dev/random | util -input -
```

providing that your util reads from stdin if `-` is specified.

Also note that the command is using the non-blocking random source.